# Name of integration techniques

Tags: calculus

Consider following integrations :

$$\int \sec^3 x\ dx,\ \int \cos\ x\ e^x\ dx $$

These can be calculated by integration by parts.

But here for instance to calculate the latter example,

we meet

$$\ast\ \int e^x \cos \ x\ dx = e^x \sin\ x + e^x \cos\ x   - \int e^x \cos \ x dx $$

Note that the integration we want to calculate appears again.

It is as like reduction formula for $\int \cos^n x\ dx$.

Here is there a name of integration technique in $\ast$ ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I think it should still be called integration by parts, but that's just me.

Comment: @Mhenni: The question is explicit: Does this technique have a name, and if so, what is it?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Not really.

Comment: As @Tunococ said, it falls under the general heading of integration by parts, though it’s a pretty clearcut special type within that broader category. To the best of my knowledge it has no standard name, however.

Comment: @Mhenni: Yes, really. There is no reasonable way not to recognize what is being asked here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: What I asked is not wrong in general. Because the whole process is nothing but integration by parts. So it turned out to be he was asking about a specific step in it.

Comment: @Mhenni: Not really: he’s asking about a specific *type* of integration by parts, the kind in which you end up solving algebraically for the integral after you’ve done a couple of integrations by parts. This is very clear from the examples chosen and the mention of reduction formulas.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: In general, the integration process has not ended yet untill this step will be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My calculus professor called this the "Recursion method."  I do not think that is standard, but it does make sense.

Comment: It makes sense only superficially, since the method doesn’t actually involve a recursive calculation; it’s just a less direct way of expressing the original integral in terms of an expression not involving an integral. I don’t know of any good short name; *use-partial-fractions-twice-and-solve-for-the-integral* is a recognizable description, but not exactly a handy name!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is still integration by parts. This is actually one of its other forms, using this to solve an equation for your integral above. It's just strange since many times integration by parts is not like that, but I use it sometimes too and it's rather effective...